# Hibernate 6.x.x CALCULATED FIELDS in createNativeQuery (oracle) doExtract integer insted of BigDecimals

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

The Oracle PL/SQL Native SUM function (calcaulated field) is not working as expected, it is converting float to integer values, the next is a following example:

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Object[]> testSUMError() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    
    Query objQuery = session.createNativeQuery("""
        SELECT 
            19.80 COLUMN_OK, \
            SUM(39.74) COLUMN_FAIL \
        FROM DUAL                                                                      
    """, Object.class);
    
    return (ArrayList<Object[]>) objQuery.list();
}
```

If we test the SELECT the return object is:

[result of the SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQMC9.png)

as you can see, the 39 is not even rounding, it only deletes the decimals.

Entorno
Hibernate-core 6.2.2.Final
Java 17
Jakarta 10
Spring Boot 3.1.0

I make the bug report to Hibernate but no luck with any dev, and I need to find a solution, without editting the Query.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-16697

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your SUM function inside a ROUND?  ROUND(SUM(39.74), 2) should preserve two decimal places

Comment: It probably works, but since is a production app, trying to find a global solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a global solution.  If the code is wrong, you'll have to change it, even if you implement a new function in Oracle that does what you need, you'll have to change the code.

Comment: the code is not bad. Hibernate 6 changes caused calculated fields to be incorrectly interpreted as integers. if you run the same code in PL/SQL hibernate 5 it works as it should.

I'm looking for a workaround while someone in hibernate catches the bug. Or hopefully get it to the attention of a hibernate specialist who has the ability to fix the bug in core.

Comment: I was wrong in thinking that SUM was truncating the decimals; it isn't.  However, are you certain that this is an issue in hibernate?  I don't have access to an Oracle database, but I ran that same native query against a postgresDB with hibernate version 6.2.2, boot 3.1.0, java 17, jakarta persistence 3.1.0, and I got back a list of two BigDecimals.  Perhaps this is something in the Oracle driver?  I tested this by creating the query directly off the entity manager, as well as from a session unwrapped from the entity manager, both produced the same results.

Comment: we are trying to someone to fix this, it has been declared as bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16697

Comment: It's open source, and you've done the leg work already to track down the potential issue.  Consider making the changes in a snapshot, test it locally, and if it fixes the issue, submit a PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed at: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-16697

At.: Hibernate-6.2.5.Final